# For this integral to be bounded, do I need density $f(x)>\delta>0$, or simply $f(x)>0$, and why?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Suppose I have integral $I\equiv\int_{R}\frac{1}{f(x)}B(x)dx$, where $B(x)$ is uniformly bounded on $R$, and $R\equiv[-\infty,\infty]$, and $f(x)$ is a density function satisfying $\int_{R} f(x)dx=1$.

If I want $I<\infty$, do I need $f(x)>0$ or $f(x)>\delta>0$ for any $x\in R$?

My guess is that we need  $f(x)>\delta>0$.

Comment: if  $f(x) > \delta > 0$ for any $x$ in $R$, it certainly works since you can bound $f$ by $\frac{1}{\delta}$. If the infimum of $f$ is zero then you need more information from $B$. For instance, consider $\frac{1}{|x|}$

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra You are wrong. The integration here is not over a set of finite measure so $f \geq \delta$ is also not good enough.

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra Thank you very much!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks, that's very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want $I$ finite, you need different conditions on $f(x)$.  For $x$ ~ $0$, $|f(x)|\lt |x|^a$ where $a\lt 1$.  For $|x|  \to \infty$, $|f(x)|\gt |x|^b$, where $b\gt 1$.

Putting a bound on $f(x)$ will work only when the the integration domain is finite.

Comment: Thanks! I also know that $f(x)$ is a density function satisfying $\int_R f(x)dx=1$, does this help?

Comment: If $\int_R f(x)dx$ is finite, $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ can be integrated over only a finite interval, since $|f(x)|\to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.